# Google Fonts Lining Numbers

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm using the [Raleway](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway) font and Google Font's description says that "the download features both old style and **lining numerals**".

I can't find any documentation that says *how* to line numerals. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 14):

**To answer my own question:**

First I had to add `&subset=all` as a parameter for the Google font:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then I just added this CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
        -ms-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
         -o-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
            font-feature-settings: "lnum";
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine on Firefox but I can't get it to work in Chrome. Were you able to? I'm using the same font and everything.

Comment: @Concept211 it works for me on `Chrome 54.0.2840.71 (Official Build) m (64-bit)` on Windows 10.

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome OS X 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit).  Here's a test fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ls8va9jg/

Comment: I can get this to work with a font weight of 400, but nothing else

Answer (score 0):

This is a old post but it's a relevant problem with this kind of fonts.

I just solved this problem using the Expert mode on https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Upload the Raleway fonts, scroll down to "OpenType flattening" and select "Lining numerals" and after click "Download your kit". Enjoy your font with the proper lining.

[OpenType flattening option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3r8b.png)