# Safari and font-feature-settings: "lnum" failing

Tags: css, safari

After going crazy trying to figure out why `font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1` was having no effect when it is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature) and well [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098992/google-fonts-lining-numbers), it seems that Safari might be to blame.

Seeing failure in both Safari 11.1.2 and 12.0.2 on macOS, and 12 on iOS.

I'm interested to hear of any others seeing this and on what versions. Can check if you see lining numerals on this [pen](https://codepen.io/marsspider/pen/XjaOOx?editors=1100).

Other `font-feature-settings` do seem seem to be [working](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) in Safari.

Comment: Still doesn't work on the latest versions of Safari on macOS and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Raleway in Google Fonts does not include the lining numerals feature.

It appears that Chrome may be using a built-in copy of Raleway; at least network inspector doesn't show it actually loading remote font files.  Perhaps that's why the pen works on Chrome but not on Safari.

The solution, then, is to use a copy of Raleway that actually includes the lining numerals feature.